# Why is Python 3x returning a list instead of a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm scratching my head over this piece of code which runs a SQL query and formats the result into a dict. But the result is returned as a list instead of a dict and I can't understand why:

```
def runSqlQuery(sqlCommand, connectString="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"):
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(connectString)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sqlCommand)
    #use the cursor column descriptions to create readable dict of results
    columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]  
    result = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor]
    print (type(result))
    return result
```

The function returns nicely formatted SQL results like:
[{'Column1': '123', 'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': '39'}]

But why is it a list when I'm clearly using the dict keyword? Is it due to the [] brackets?

Comment: yes, `[]` creates a list comprehension.

Comment: Did you mean to use a dict comprehension instead of a list comprehension? `dict(zip(columns, row) for row in cursor)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor]
```

this line is a list comprehension - it creates a list by iterating over the `row`s in `cursor` and creating a dict for each row. So the result is a `list` of `dict`s

I think you will find that this line

```
all([isinstance(item, dict) for item in result])
```

produces a `True` result - that is, each of the items in the list is a `dict`

Comment: It's better to compare types with `is` instead of `==`.  Even better (since it handles subclasses) would be `isinstance(item, dict)`.